# How to fix width of column in SpGridView?

Tags: 2010, column, spgridview, gridview

I have a spgridview with dynamic column.

I want fix width and if the content is a part of it is displayed.

I use this code but don't work for me .

```
BoundField col = new BoundField();
col.HeaderText = field.Title;
col.HeaderStyle.Width = new Unit(50);
col.DataField = field.InternalName;
```

for fix height i use this code.

```
  e.Row.Height = new Unit(25);
            if (grid.Columns.Count > 1)
                for (int i = 1; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Wrap = false;
                }
```

Comment: How does the css look like? Is it somewhere there that makes the text unwrap or set the table cells sizes? Otherways you can control it there which I belive is the best thing and not by units from ASP.NET (which will be inline css).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?     `grid.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width = 200`

Comment: Thanks, i use this code but don't work. it is fix with content :(

Answer (score 0):

It should be `col.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);`

Comment: Thanks, i use this code but don't work. it is fix with content :(

Answer (score 0):

Create an handler for the RowDataBound event of the grid and inside that handler set the width for the cells. You can use something similar to the following:

```
e.Row.Cells[x].Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView column normally contains the Width property to [size width of column](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_column_resize.shtml) and change the width for a particular column.